# Adicionar programa ao shell do windows

Tags: windows, shell

Preciso de adicionar um programa ao shell do windows para o puder chamar mais comodamente.

No ambiente linux costumo criar um soft link entre o programa e a pasta de instalação de programas, segue um exemplo:

```
ln -s /opt/sublime-text/sublime-text /usr/bin/sublime-text
```

Depois posso:

```
sublime-text index.php
```

Qual seria a melhor solução para reproduzir o mesmo resultado no Windows 10?

Já arranjei um solução utilizando as variáveis de ambiente do windows, porém gostaria de saber se existe outro método para obter o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava a adicionar ás variáveis de ambiente do windows a variável "Programa" - "localização do exe". Em vez disso adicionei o caminho da pasta do programa á variável PATH e funciona a 100%

Ou seja, para resolver basta adicionar a localização da pasta do programa á variável de ambiente PATH.